# Android File Specific Volume

Tags: android

I've got an application where I will be playing 2 audio files simultaneously and the user will be attempting to hear the one (spoken words) over the other (background noise).  With successful feedback input that they heard the file correctly, I want to decrease the volume of 1 (words) of the 2 files and play it again and they will attempt to hear it over the noise.  I only want to decrease the volume of one file... the other one needs to remain constant (otherwise it defeats the purpose of trying to hear the one over the other).  All I've found so far with the MediaManager is the ability to change the global volume of the application and not the specific audio clips within the application.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My impression that the media player was global was incorrect.  You can set the volume for this file and it will keep that volume even when you play a louder or quieter file (even when using the same mp).  The oncompletion listener is important to releasing the file when over other wise you'll get exceptions and lose all sound.  The logarithmic math function is important to getting the volume to scale appropriately between 0 & 100.

Assuming MAX_VOLUME is 100:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.noise);
        final float noisevolume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - 50) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
        mp.setVolume(noisevolume, noisevolume);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
```